# Arm A-profile architecture: what does ZA stand for?

Tags: arm, terminology, acronym

This is a simple question, however, in Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture (issue I.a) I cannot find an answer.

What does ZA stand for?

Some examples (from the document above):

- ZA mode
- ZA tile
- ZA tile storage
- ZA array

Some resources mentioning ZA:

- [https://arm-software.github.io/acle/main/acle.html#introduction-to-za-storage\](https://arm-software.github.io/acle/main/acle.html#introduction-to-za-storage%5C)
- https://reviews.llvm.org/D105570

Comment: what did arm say when you asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZA is the name of a large 2-dimensional array register that is part of the Armv9-A [Scalable Matrix Extension (SME)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0616/latest).  It is described in Chapter B2 of that document (I'm using version A.a).  Arm's docs often refer to it as "storage" instead of as a register, probably due to its size of at least 256 bytes (the square of the scalable vector length).

The A in ZA presumably stands for "array".  I don't think the Z stands for anything but matches the Z0-Z31 naming for SVE registers.

Specifically:

- "ZA mode" refers to the state when "ZA storage is enabled", which can be selected with appropriate MSR instructions (see B1.1.1.3).  The ZA register is only accessible in this mode.
- A "ZA tile" is a square sub-matrix of ZA.  See B2.2.2.

Comment: Thanks! Re: "The A in ZA presumably stands for "array": just wondering why document "Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture" does not have "Definitions, abbreviations, and acronyms" (or similar) section.

Comment: @pmor: It does have one, the "Glossary" at the very end of the document.  The SME supplement has one too.  They don't explain ZA, though, probably because it isn't important whether ZA means or stands for anything or not.  As far as that document is concerned, it might as well be a purely arbitrary name for a particular register.  We can guess at why the name might have been chosen, and/or invent mnemonics for ourselves, but the Architecture Reference Manual is a formal spec and none of that is relevant to it.